# Are integers in Bash signed by default?

Tags: bash

I suspect that, by default, integers in Bash are always signed unless they exceed a specific positive value that cannot be represented in two's complement notation. Is that so? Is it documented?

I have done much research but have not found confirmation of this.

Comment: bash doesn't really have "integers". When you store a number in a variable, it's a string (that happens to be a sequence of digits). When you do math in bash, it parses those strings into integers (of a platform-dependent type), does the math, then converts the result back to a string of digits for storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the changelog](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/CHANGES#L6687), since Bash 2.05b,

> j.  The shell now performs arithmetic in the largest integer size the
> machine supports (intmax_t), instead of long.

`intmax_t` is indeed a signed type.